# Name for the type of relation similar to the edge set of a regular directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, relations

For a binary relation over a set, if each member in the set appears the same number of times in the first position and in the second position in the relation, is there a name for such a relation?

For example, in a $k$-regular directed graph, the in-degrees and the out-degrees of all the vertices are $k$. What it says is that in the edge set, each vertex appears $k$ times in the first position, and $k$ times in the second position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are graphs where the in-degree of each vertex is the same as its out-degree. These graphs receive the name of [balanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree).

Comment: Thanks. but am asking about the relation only, not necessarily in graph theory.Ｍ